# SolrCloud backup data not finding on my system path

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr6

When I ran the SolrCloud (6.3.0) Back API using this url [backup url](http://localhose:8983/solr/admin/collections?%20action=BACKUP&name=locations_back&collection=locations&location=/)

It returns response **status 0** i.e **no error**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">213</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="success">
        <lst name="localhost:8983_solr">
            <lst name="responseHeader">
                <int name="status">0</int>
                <int name="QTime">43</int>
            </lst>
        </lst>
    </lst>
</response>
```

But I didn't find any **locations_back** folder with backed up data on my system.

When I ran this curl from command line, it returns some numbers like **32058, 32059,32060** etc.

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=BACKUP&name=locations_back&collection=locations&location=/opt/solr/server/solr

[1] 32058
[2] 32059
[3] 32060
```

Where I tested with location param path **location=/opt/solr/server/solr**  OR  **location =/**

But It also didn't show any **locations_back** folder with backed up data on my system.

Comment: Sarah, can you please clarify what exactly you are asking including the expected behaviour? Thank you.

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh simply I just want to backup and restore  my solr collections  using the collection api for solr 6.3.0 on solrcloud environment.

Comment: Does your Solr server actually have write permissions to `/`? That doesn't sound very good if it had. Does it have write permissions to `/opt/solr/server/solr`? You'll also need to wrap the argument to `curl` in `""`, as `&` is interpreted as "do this in the background" in bash, so you're not doing anything useful with that command.

Comment: @MatsLindh Permission on folder `/opt/solr/server/solr` is 777 and still it returns some numbers like 32557,32558 & 32559 after curl request . If I change curl request with some `""` it returns `curl: (7) Failed to connect to server_ip_goes_here  port 8983: Connection timed out`

Comment: The 3255, 32558 .. etc is only local PID numbers as the `&` makes your shell launch multiple processes that doesn't go anywhere. If you're unable to connect to Solr on the given ip, something is up - are you sure that Solr is listening on the ip, are you issuing the command from the same machine that the browser is running on, etc?

Comment: @MatsLindh, yes solr ip is working when I query documents from admin UI. But not while try to run curl command for backup collection data on my current machine :( except it returns some process Ids

Answer (score 0):

In order to troubleshoot this issue please check the following:

1. modify the backup folder from /opt/solr/server/solr to /tmp/ That will help you understanding if it's a permission problem;
2. Is your collection really called locations (as one of your params is collection=locations)? Change it as necessary
3. Check the Solr server logs in order to see what's the error;
4. Is SSH enabled or are you hitting a firewall?
5. Are your Solr nodes healthy?
6. Are you calling that url through a browser or programmatically?